# `Cant Upload WebGL build in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

i am trying to upload a simple webgl build in unity the build size is about 15 megabytes
but when i try to use the local router network dsl line it always gives this error

`Curl error 56: Receiving data failed with unitytls error code 1048578`

but when i use my mobile network it uploads just fine i think it is a network thing
so i cant really figure out whats going on

these are my player settings [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJADS.png)

Comment: Why do you think it s a unity problem if your mobile network uploads fine

Comment: i said i think it is a network problem and i hoped someone who uses unity went through the same thing using webgl thats why i put the unity tag

Comment: Still doesn’t make it a SO issue. Speak to your isp or unity to talk you through working out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the isp and well they knew nothing about unity
Using a cable to connect to the internet solved the problem with me
So it might be something wrong with the router's wifi settings